# Are principle of virtual work and principle of minimum potential energy same? And how is it related to Calculus of variation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work, potential-energy, variational-principle

I am studying Finite element method and Classical Mechanics. I have come across three important terms

1. [Principle of virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) (found in Classical Mechanics)
2. [Principle of minimum potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_total_potential_energy_principle) (found in Finite element method)
3. [Calculus of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) (found in Mathematics while searching concept of Variational method of Finite element method)

All above terms are being used interchangeably and in bits and pieces in different book and no book did not explain properly about the relation of those three terms.

I feel that there are some relationship but not able to figure it out.

Can someone explain all these three terms and how these are inter related?

Comment: Do some research at least. The first sentence of the article on calculus of variations starts with "... is a field of mathematical analysis", which clearly makes it distinct from principles used in it. Distinguishing 1 and 2 is not as easy, I grant you that. :)